# Allow user to paste in "Tab-delimited" data into a textarea

Tags: php, mysql, csv, tabs, textarea

My question is how do I allow a user to Paste in tab delimited data into a textarea on a website and then store and parse that data to run some action against it.

For example at http://www.batchgeo.com you can paste in your address location and from that a map is generated via the google maps api. I'm not looking for a step by step answer just what is happening on the server side of things to store and parse the data.

Comment: In Excel?  If the data is tab-delimted then why not just have them paste it onto a worksheet?

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks for you input and I agree that it was a poorly asked question. I have revised it and hope it helps clear the question up.

Comment: @Justjoe +1 its good to see people on this site turn connoisseur:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive data into a PHP script, just set up a form that POSTs to it:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
<textarea name="data" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Next, create the PHP script to receive the data:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    # do something with $data...
?>
```

What comes next depends on what you want to do with that data.